# Keras TimeDistributed Dense drops vector dimension by 1

Tags: keras, lstm

I am not able to figure out how the tensor dimension got reduced by 1 in the TimeDistributed Dense step in the following

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(vocab_size +1, 128, input_length=unravel_len))  # embedding shape: (99, 15, 128)
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(64, return_sequences=True)))   # (99, 15, 128)
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(categories, activation='softmax')))    # (99, 15, 127)
```

I labeled the tensor shape along each step. You can see the last dimension dropped from 128 to 127. Can someone explain why that is. Thanks

Comment: Chances are the size of `categories` is 127.

Comment: you are totally right.I don't know how I missed that.